# Route 53 Alias is not redirecting to elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an alias in a hosted zone in `Route 53` which has an alias name to route traffic to my `elastic beanstalk` environment URl but if I visit the alias in Browser it shows "Site not found".

This is the screenshot of the `route 53` in the hosted zones where I have a hosted zone and an alias record to my specified resource.

[image]

The resource is totally up and running without any error

Comment: Probably your record hasn't been propagated. Also check this for TTL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-basic.html#rrsets-values-basic-ttl

Comment: Try clearing your DNS cache.

Comment: iicmybondhuserver-env.eba-fmsmrizf.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com does not seem reachable.

Answer (score 0):

iicmybondhuserver-env.eba-fmsmrizf.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com does not seem reachable.

If I check my app url of Elastic Beanstalk its much shorter and looks like "app-name.aws-region.elasticbeanstalk.com".

Please check before filling in your ALIAS record if its accessible.

[This is how](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-get-domain-name) you get your alias record in Elastic Beanstalk.